# Bert Fine tuning takes a lot of time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have to do a text classification task with 28 possible classes. I decided to load BERT's model as a pre-trained model and to fine tune it for solving my problem. The thing is that the training is extremely slow (on GPU) whereas I  made sure to freeze BERT's layers so that I only have to train a Dense Layer at the end. Here is the code I used to create my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from transformers import TFDistilBertModel, DistilBertConfig

distil_bert = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
def Bert(out_shape,max_seq_length):

 config = DistilBertConfig(dropout=0.2, attention_dropout=0.2)
 config.output_hidden_states = False
 transformer_model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained(distil_bert, config = config)

 input_ids_in = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
 input_masks_in = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32') 

 embedding_layer = transformer_model(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]
 #X = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))(embedding_layer)
 X = GlobalMaxPool1D()(embedding_layer)
 #X = Flatten()(embedding_layer)
 #X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
 #X = Dense(2*len(categories), activation='relu')(X)
 X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
 X = Dense(out_shape, activation='softmax')(X)

 model = Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in], outputs = X)

 for layer in model.layers[:3]:
   layer.trainable = False

 return model

model = Bert(len(categories),MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
model.summary()
```

Here is the summary:

[image]

As you can see, I only have 22.000 parameters to learn I don't understand why it takes so long per epoch (almost 10 min). Before using BERT, I used a classic Bidirectional LSTM model with more than 1M parameters and it only took 15 seconds per epoch.

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: Even if you freeze Bert, you still have a to do the forward pass which will be often more computationally intensive for a model with 66M parameters than for a Network with 1M.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar result. I use keras-bert to train a BERT model to do a classification task. However, when I freeze all the layers inside BERT, it will take 10mins per epoch, but when I unfreeze even only one layer, it will take about 25mins per epoch. What is interesting is if I unfreeze all layers (make all parameters trainable), it will take about 30mins per epoch.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32317478)